# Overlap a "Tutorial View" over the standard layout

Tags: java, android, layout

I want to overlap some views explaining the interface over the layout of a screen like in this image [image]

So changed the layout to:

```
RootLayout
    AppLayout
    TutorialLayout (FrameLayout)
```

And I want to position the views in the TutorialLayout changing its margins according to the views in the AppLayout.

How can I get the global margins of a view in the AppLayout? I tested `View.getLocationOnScreen`, `View.getGlobalVisibleRect` and `View.getLocationInWindow` but all of them return values incuding the status bar, and the app title.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try dividing your tutorial into different views that are laid out exactly as the ones in the background.

You would use one image per view and have to split your image into multiple images, but this way you would delegate the coordinate calculations to the layout manager and wouldn't have to calculate them yourself.

Edit:

A drawback of using this method is that if you want your tutorial to cover the menu bar, you would actually have to work around it by displaying the tutorial image under menu bar, with arrows pointing upward to the menu entries and not on top of them.